# Two Player Tic Tac Toe Game in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make my own Tic Tac Toe game, I am new to Javascript and it has been two days, and I am unable to reach anything concrete... So far.. I have achieved this in my game- http://jsfiddle.net/f9sV4/

```
//Tic Tac Toe
//Global Variables
//Get input from user about which sign should be for playerOne.
//Set signs for both players.
//When user click on button it triggers play function()
//Play function detects who is playing this turn.
//Display Sign on that button accordingly.
var playerOneChoice;
var playerTwoChoice;
var playerTurn=1;
var matrix = [[], [], []];
var buttons = [[], [], []];
var row1;
var X = "X";
var O = "O";
var x;
var y;
var i;

//Input the matrix
for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0: x=0; y=0; break;
    case 1: x=0; y=1; break;
    case 2: x=0; y=2; break;
    case 3: x=1; y=0; break;
    case 4: x=1; y=1; break;
    case 5: x=1; y=2; break;
    case 6: x=2; y=0; break;
    case 7: x=2; y=1; break;
    case 8: x=2; y=2; break;
    }
    matrix[x][y] = document.querySelector(".cell"+i);
    buttons[x][y] = document.querySelector("#b"+i);
    //matrix[x][y].innerHTML = i + " " + x + " " + y;
}
function play() {
displayOutput();

incPlayerTurn();
}
function displayTurn() {
    var display = document.querySelector("#playerTurn");
    if (playerTurn%2==0)
        display.innerHTML ="Its player two turn";
    else
        display.innerHTML ="Its player one turn";
}    
function incPlayerTurn(){
    playerTurn++;
}
function displayOutput(){
    if (playerTurn%2 == 1)
        this.innerHTML = playerOneChoice;
    else
        this.innerHTML = playerTwoChoice;
}
function setO(){
    playerOneChoice="O";
    playerTwoChoice="X"
}
function setX(){
    playerOneChoice="X";
    playerTwoChoice="O"
}

function displayO(){
var butt = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
 butt[i].onclick = function(e) {
 this.innerHTML ="O";
    };
}
}

function displayX(){
var butt = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
    butt[i].onclick = function(e) {
 this.innerHTML ="X";
    };
}
}
```

Now, I am not sure, how can I know which button is clicked, and then how can I set it to "O" or "X" as per user choice.

I thought it would be simple game to design but it looks like it has got much complicated.

Comment: RE The for-switch-case pattern. Have you not heard of `for (i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) { for (j = 0; j <= 2; ++j) { do stuff } }` style nested loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I know which button is clicked

Inside the function that was assigned to the onclick property of the button, 'this' represents the button that was clicked.

> how can I set it to "O" or "X" as per user choice.

Buttons have a value property, which changes the button's text, e.g:

```
this.value = "X"
```

You will have to get the user choice somehow, store it, then read it from inside the onclick function.  Or, you could make it so your button just changes between 'X' and 'O' every time it is clicked.

```
this.value = (this.value == "X") ? "O" : "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reduce the complexity of your code, both HTML and JS, you can see the fork here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4AMq9/

Hope now is more clean and easier to understand and manipulate to achieve your goal. One of major change was remove the matrix and the listeners for each button. Because the event are propagated, you can delegate a parent element to handle them. Here a clear example:

```
playerchoice.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if (event.target.value === "O")
        players.reverse();

    this.disabled = true;
    playarea.style.display = "block";

    displayTurn();
}, false);
```

In this case `this` is referring to the element `playerchoice` were `event.target` is the nested element's that fired the event.

Notice that a matrix would be still useful to determined when a player wins, but my impression was that you tried to mix the logic with the UI – something that is common in the web, that's why I also removed the listener's HTML attribute.

Hope it helps!